# Ad successfully loads but ad not showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, ads

im new here and new to app developing, im trying to make a banner ad in my app, heres the codes ive setup:

in build.gradle(:app) dependencies:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:21.1.0' implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.0' implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.1.0'`

in AndroidManifest.xml: (in the application quote)

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />
```

in activity_xxx.xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />
```

in AdActivity:

```
public class EntryActivity extends BaseActivity {
private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xxx);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            Log.w("AdActivity", String.valueOf(adError));
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            Log.w("AdActivity","AD LOADED SUCCESFULLY !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    });
}
```

}

im using the app test ID and unit test ID, i get the `AD LOADED SUCCESFULLY` log in the logcat, but the ad is not showing, it was showing errors before but they gone. i havent got any ad shown so far, thanks for listening and waiting your useful replys.

Edit: edited app ID, i was using mine one when i copied the code.

Comment: care, people can see the edits history!

Comment: wow cool, this my first post :P

Comment: `AdView` can have a `view` that overlaps. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow [this](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/quick-start) guide you can see they have mentioned Sample Ad Manager app ID.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />
```

Try to use this one and let me know if it works.

Comment: its not working too, i tried a real device with testing mode on my app's and ad unit ids too, i get ad successfully loaded from my log command but no ad is appearing.